# Silverlight listbox binding question

Tags: silverlight

I have a list which is bound to an observable collection of custom class. Works perfect.

What I want to do us add a row in the last which is not a part of observable collection whenever it comes into view it should trigger a function to load more items in to listbox.

Thanks
Erphan Rajput

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Is the creation of items to be added to the collection expensive?  Are you using a standard ListBox control?

Comment: It is possible, but not as a last row in a listbox. It will look as a separated control.

Comment: Are you trying to load data into the collection incrementally?

Comment: It's like auto paging... http api returns 10 records when user sees last record in listbox it should automatically goes to http api in background and fetch more records for user... User doesn't have to press a button or select from menu, it should be automated, that the main purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The ListBox default template looks something like this:

```
<Border ...>
  <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" ...>
    <ItemsPresenter />
  </ScrollViewer>
</Border>
```

The `ItemsPresenter` is the one that renders the elements from the `ItemsSource`.

What about you override the default template to something like:

```
<Border ...>
  <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" ...>
    <StackPanel>
      <ItemsPresenter ... />
      <!-- Your Control Here -->
    </StackPanel>
  </ScrollViewer>
</Border>
```

Comment: How is it then detected that this extra control has been scrolled to?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out a way to do this please suggest if this is the right approach considering the current limitations from Silverlight controls.

in XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="MyListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding MyObservableCollection}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemDisplayTemplate}"
    ManipulationCompleted="MyListBox_ManipulationCompleted"/>
```

in CS:

```
private void MyListBox_ManipulationCompleted(object sender,
        System.Windows.Input.ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    ScrollViewer sv = Utility.FindScrollViewerRecursive((ListBox)sender);
    int a = Int32.Parse(Math.Round(sv.VerticalOffset).ToString()) +
        Int32.Parse(Math.Round(sv.ViewportHeight).ToString());
    if ((a + 1) >= sv.ExtentHeight)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Should start loading new items in background");
    }
    Debug.WriteLine(sv.VerticalOffset + " - " + sv.ViewportHeight + " - " + sv.ExtentHeight);
}
```

I have taken the FindScrollViewerRecursive from here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rohantha/archive/2010/09/12/silverlight-wp7-list-scroll-with-items-as-image-description-from-web-bing-image-search.aspx

I'll post the full sample source code soon... for now please suggest if this method is OK.

Comment: This looks like a valid approach, although some of the code could probably be written in a better fashion. `int a = Int32.Parse(Math.Round(sv.VerticalOffset).ToString())`? Really?

Comment: Yes! It can be I just did this for better understand and logging... this can be done like if((sv.VerticalOffest + sv.ViewportHeight + 1) >= sv.ExtendedHeight) { // load new data } +1 is for a little earlier than most end of the scrollbar - Plus also check if ScrollViewer is not null...